# VHDL: unknown signal assignment

Tags: vhdl

this is my first time on stackexchange and I have a question. 
I have a project and I have to write a vhdl code but when i simulate i get a unknown output.  I don't know why but i dont get a error at compiling. It is just a simple fsm that take a average of 8 bit vector. can someone tell me what is wrong? thx

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;

entity delay is
port(mem_in       :in    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    flag_in_mem  :in    std_logic;
    reset        :in    std_logic;
clk      :in       std_logic;
enable       :in    std_logic;
    flag_out_main:out   std_logic;
    data_out     :out   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end delay;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

architecture behaviour of delay is

type delay_state is (main, regi, calc);
signal state, new_state: delay_state;
signal reg, new_reg,buff, new_buff : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal test : std_logic;

begin 

lbl1 : process(clk,reset) 

begin
if(reset='1') then
state <= main;
reg <=(others =>'0');
     data_out<=(others =>'0');
    flag_out_main<='0';
elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then
     state <= new_state;
     reg <= new_reg;
     buff <= new_buff;

 end if;
end process;

lbl2 :  process(mem_in, enable, state, flag_in_mem, reg,buff)

begin
new_state <= state;
new_reg<=reg;
  case state is
      when main => 
        flag_out_main<='0';
        if (flag_in_mem='1' and enable='1') then
         new_state<=calc;
        end if;
    when calc =>
        new_buff <= std_logic_vector((unsigned(mem_in) + unsigned(reg))/2);
        flag_out_main<='1';
        new_state<=regi;    
    when regi =>    
        if(enable='0') then
        new_reg<=buff;
        new_state<=main;
        end if;
end case;

end process;

   data_out<=reg;

   end behaviour;
```

Comment: Are you expecting us to read your uncommented and inconsistently-indented code to work out a) what you wanted it to do, and b) what it actually does? Good luck with that...

Comment: @vancongnguyen If you want help take the time and write a decent post, a professional post will get a professional answer. It would be appropriate to post a block diagram of how your system works and error codes. Not using the proper case in your sentances = unprofessional.

Answer (score 2):

The outputs `flag_out_main` and `data_out` are driven from both processes, and for `data_out` also the concurrent assign.  Such multiple drivers in a VHDL design are similar to multiple drivers on a PCB, and will result in contention if the driven value is not the same, resulting an a resolved value of `'X'`, which is probably what you see.

Only drive each signal or output from a single process (but it is OK to have multiple assigns inside the same process) or concurrent assign.

Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).